# What are advantages of "cp" over "rsync"?

Tags: rsync, cp

It seems that rsync can do all the work of cp.

Comment: IMO rsync is superior to cp , but it is a matter of choice / opinion. cp is less typing ? your question is more an opinion then support

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes, I am just wondering whether there are disadvantages of using "rsync", such as efficiency, stability, etc.

Comment: see http://serverfault.com/questions/43014/copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally-cp-or-rsync and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44384/cp-or-rsync-is-cp-really-worth-it . mainly opinions and options

Comment: please refer my answer=) @WeiChen

Answer (score 3):

`cp` is a part of coreutils, therefore it is present everywhere. furthermore, it primarily was designed to copy files inside one computer.

`rsync` isn't a part of coreutils, it isn't present even on the default environment. It was primarily designed to transfer files over network. Also rsync has more dependencies comparing to coreutils, however this difference doesn't make a big sense.

The main advantage of cp over rsync is time and less cpu usage .

Reference [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/43014/copying-a-large-directory-tree-locally-cp-or-rsync),[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44384/cp-or-rsync-is-cp-really-worth-it),[here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-cp-and-rsync),[here](http://blog.mudy.info/2010/07/linux-file-copy-benchmark-cp-vs-cpio-vs-tar-vs-rsync/),[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339287/copy-or-rsync-command) and [here](http://www.crucialp.com/resources/tutorials/server-administration/how-to-copy-files-across-a-network-internet-in-unix-linux-redhat-debian-freebsd-scp-tar-rsync-secure-network-copy/)

Comment: @WeiChen fell free to accept my answer by clicking tick mark on left side of my answer